# Find out BIOS Version from Windows

Tags: windows-10, bios

How can I find out BIOS version in Windows without rebooting the system? I would gladly spare finding out the shortcut to enter BIOS and search in BIOS.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you'd need it for that you don't need to restart, and that you'd trust windows to tell you what it is.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> & enter 
`msinfo32`

Then you can navigate and look for all kinds of information, including the BIOS version.

Comment: In fact, since Windows Vista, pressing the Win key and typing msinfo32 will also work.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Run is faster though. You might have to wait up to 3 seconds because the indexing for Windows search is the worst IMO (at least until Win7).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: I know. On my Windows 7 PC, though, it is very fast. But I also have a Windows 10 PC, and there - for some reason - it is much slower.

Comment: "It works on my machine"

Answer (score 28):

You also can find out your BIOS version on `cmd` typing:

```
wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion
```

It will return only the version. `msinfo32` will provide you all the information about the BIOS.

Comment: A black window appears but it vanishes as quickly as it appears. I wonder what could be added to the command line to make this "DOS screen" stay.

Comment: @CopperKettle You should use the command line, not the run box. You'll want `cmd /k "wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion"` for that.

Answer (score 14):

As a third option using Powershell:

```
 Get-WmiObject win32_bios
```

You can find the other possible properties by piping Get-WmiObject win32_bios to get-member to show the other possible properties.

Comment: You don't have to type "select SMBIOSBIOSversion" just read it from the line! Nonetheless +1 good answer!

Comment: Ah, I added that part after checking to see what information the OP was seeking, and didn't catch that it was visible by default, since there's a lot of information that Powershell doesn't show by default.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a registry key containing the BIOS version, which could be useful if you need to access this information from some software:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\SystemBiosVersion
```

Comment: In Powershell: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\ | Select SystemBiosVersion` (With more detail) or `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS\ | Select BIOSVersion` (Just raw version string same as @Davidw 's answer)

Comment: +1 Good for the first! But plz descripe also how! Open CMD -> `systeminfo | findstr /I /c:bios` -> `wmic bios get manufacturer, smbiosbiosversion` -> `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS` -> view for "BIOSVersion"

Answer (score 1):

**If you like to use third-party software ...**

[CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can do this :

[image: CPU-Z Screen Shot]

Of course there are several other tools that can give you this information, you just have to Google for *System information software*!